# Looping through list of models in view without refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to loop through list of models and update displayed data in view without refreshing the page or making ajax call to server?

Scenario:

Model:

```
public SomeModel 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LinkName { get; set; }    
    public string ItemDecsiption { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

List of SomeModel objects is inicialized, filled with data and passed to View in controller ActionResult. I can see all data in view (i am able to loop through individual models and create list from SomeModel.LinkName property.

```
<ul>
<%  foreach (SomeNamespace.SomeModel m in Model)
{ %>
    <li class="green"><%= m.LinkName %></li>
<%  } %>
</ul>
```

What I want to do is to divide page content section into two parts-one with menu (consisting of links created from every LinkName in Model) and second containing block with description and text (for id currently clicked in menu). Now comes the trick part. I want to be able to change displayed data in second block after clicking Link in menu without refreshing the page or making ajax call to server (since all the data I need is already available to client side). Only solution I could think of is to generate hidden blocks for every SomeModel object and then write jquery to manipulate visibility after link click. What I want to know is if there is some more elegant way to accomplish this.

Project is written in C#.NET 3.5 ASP.NET MVC 2.0

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the markup which you'll produce, hidden html blocks may be the most elegant solution of all. Like, for intance, if you switch visibility by simply changing a class of block which should be visible without changing the DOM.

The other option will be to prepare json object from `Model` and use it as data source for visible markup. But this may lead to raise of complexity which is not necessary in most of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this would be to use JavaScript to manipulate the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

there is another way.
1.var data=@Model.ToJson() in js; there is not a ToJson function ,that just what you need to do
2.only one content block
3.when click menu,find element in data,and set block content use js